# preg_match how to negate preceding zeros in a phone number?

Tags: php, regex

I'm just learning regular expressions so I could use some help on this topic regarding the validation of phone numbers.

I have a phone input that is divided into one select list with country codes prefixed with a + sign. If a user forgets to remove the preceding zero in the phone number it won't be in accordance to the E.164 international standard (There are however a handful of countries that are an exception to this rule, i.e. Italy, Norway etc). But the majority needs to omit the zero for a valid international phone number.

In my albeit limited research, I've realized that phone number formats vary significantly across the world. This means the validation needs to be loose rather than strict and allow for any combination of dashes, spaces, parenthesis, dots and forward slashes as delimiters between numbers. To fit the E.164 standard the delimiters will then be replaced by empty strings to give an example result like this: `+44755222333`

This is my attempt thus far for validating any number.

```
preg_match('/^(?:[0-9][.\-\(\)\s]*)/$', $phonenumber);
```

How would you compose a regular expression to negate preceding zeros i.e return a false match in presence of the string character 0 or 00, coupled with the flexibility to validate any possible telephone number notation?

Sincerely, Why

P.S Just to check. Does the 'no zero' rule apply for NANP numbers as well? I'm asking this because I assume the majority of the people here are familiar with that telephone numbering system.

Comment: Do you want a number like `044755222333` to return false no match or do you want every thing after the first 0 or 00

Comment: The no zero rule applies to NAND numbers too

Answer (score 2):

You can use `preg_replace` to strip off the leading zeros:

```
$phonenumber = preg_replace('/^0+/','',$phonenumber);
```

This will remove one or more zeros from the front of the string. (If you only want to remove one zero, then drop the plus sign).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks that does solve the problem in a different way. I wonder though, how would you negate a preceding zero in a preg_match that validates the input string?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$number = '044567565';
preg_match('/^0{0,2}(([0-9]*[.\-\(\)\s]*)*)/', $number, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Result:

```
array(
    [0] => 044567565
    [1] => 44567565
    [2] => 
)
```